# Get all changes made to children entities with Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    List<Bar> bars;
}
```

How do I get all changes which were made on my object having many children using Hibernate Envers? I am interested in knowing all changes made to bars (i.e. creation, modification, deletion)

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/AuditReader.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a custom event listener which extends `org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener`. You can then override anyone of the following methods to record the changes:

1. `onPostRecreateCollection`
2. `onPreRemoveCollection`
3. `onPreUpdateCollection`

You can register your custom listener in EntityManager configuration. Following is a simple example:

```xml
<prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update">
  com.bla.bla.audit.listener.AuditEventListener
</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove">
  com.bla.bla.audit.listener.AuditEventListener
</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate">
  com.bla.bla.audit.listener.AuditEventListener
</prop>
```